# Plone 4.3.x on OS X Mavericks

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

Are there any known issues with installing 4.3.x on OS X Mavericks (either binary or unified installer)? Just wondering if anyone has tested this yet. We are getting several new Macs for our designers and developers and need to know if Plone 4.3.x will install given the binary installers are Mountain Lion (10.8.x) specific.

Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't expect any problems provided you build Python from source.

Comment: If there are problems, we'll fix them. Every new version of OS X has brought its own problems, but we've always figured them out. At absolute worst, you'll have to wait a week for the binary installer, during which time you'll likely be able to use the Unified Installer.

Comment: Update: I was able to successfully install 4.3.1 from the binary installer on Mavericks. Seems to be running ok. I have not had a chance to attempt 4.3.2 from the unified installer yet. I only wanted to ask because I knew there were some major OS X changes between Snow Leopard (10.6) and Lion and Mountain Lion (10.7 & 10.8) that made the existing Plone installers fubar at the time.

Comment: Update 2: The unified installers do not work with OS X 10.9. I get an error that the C compiler is not working and unable to run the preflight check. Basically the C compiler cannot create executables. I attempted to run the unified installer both as root and non-root users.

Comment: Updated your XCode command-line tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both the binary and Unified Installers for Plone 4.3.x work with OS X 10.9.

If you wish to use the Unified Installer, you **must** update the XCode command-line tools after updating OS X. Make sure you also perform the extra step to accept the license. If you're using the ports collection, also rebuild your ports.

Comment: That worked! I did not update my command line tools after I updated Xcode. Was able to get 4.3.1 and 4.3.2 up and running using the unified installer. Thanks! Oh, and by the way, for S&G's I was able to get 4.2.6 and 4.1.6 up and running on OS X 10.9. Plone 4.0.7 failed for both the binary and unified installer. Obviously Plone 3.3.x no longer install post Snow Leopard (10.6.x).

Comment: Steve, once again you are the bomb. Thanks again for all of your tremendous help. (working on our first diazo and dexterity project - hav 2 others in the pipeline. will send you links to review when they are up and running)